# Call Function from if statement

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement

I have a button on my UI which when clicked checks the URL of the current tab compared to one which is passed in from database. If they match I want to call a function which makes an ajax call to get some data. My code is as follows:

```
('#automate').click(automateButton);


                       function automateButton() {
                            if(webpageUrl == activeTabUrl){
                                //call function here
                            }
                            else {
                                // Window opens
                                window.open(webpageUrl);
                            }
                        }
```

This is my ajax call:

```
$('#scenarioDropdownList').change(function () {
    var scenarioId = $('#scenarioDropdownList option:selected').attr('id');
    getData(scenarioId); 
    });

    function getData(scenarioId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://localhost:54442/api/scenariodatas/GetScenarioData',
            data: {scenarioId: scenarioId},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: scenarioData,
            error: function(){
                    console.log("There has been an error retrieving the data");
            }
        });
    }

    function scenarioData(response) {
        $.each(response, function(key, val) {
                var fieldType = val.fieldType;
                var fieldName = val.fieldName;
                var fieldValue = val.fieldValue;

                var field = $(fieldName);
            })
        }
```

I want to be able to call the ajax call from inside of the if statement. How would i go about this?

**EDIT**
When I have the ajax call standalone and console.log the variables I am returning the correct data. Unfortunately when I either paste it inside of the if statement or reference a function which surrounds it, the values do not get logged. No error message just doesn't work as it does when the ajax call is standalone.

Comment: Yeah i Have tried both ways but it doesn't work.

Comment: _"i Have tried both ways"_ - Why are those missing in the question? _"but it doesn't work"_ - This error "description" is useless. Please describe what happened and add any error messages (copy&paste) from the console.

Comment: In which context do you run the function `automateButton()`?

Comment: automateButton is occuring on a button click

Comment: That's obvious, what I meant is - in the context of a separate JS file, in the same file, what is the scope of JQuery?

Comment: In the same Js file

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `$('#scenarioDropdownList').change();` directly inside your if statement, to trigger the event `change` :

```js
$('#scenarioDropdownList').change(function () {
    console.log("Calling ajax");
});

$('#automate').click(automateButton);


function automateButton() {
  $('#scenarioDropdownList').change();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="scenarioDropdownList">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="automate">Automate</button>
```

Or move the content of the event for `$('#scenarioDropdownList').change(function () { ... })` in a separate function that you'll call from the if statement

```js
$('#scenarioDropdownList').change(ajaxCall);

$('#automate').click(automateButton);


function automateButton() {
  ajaxCall();
}

function ajaxCall()
{
  console.log("Calling ajax");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="scenarioDropdownList">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="automate">Automate</button>
```